# Diode and bipolar NPN transistors orientation not correct, says JLCPCB

Tags: transistors, diodes, schematics, pcb-assembly, bipolar

JLCPCB is telling me 4 components are incorrect but when I look over it and the datasheet it all seems correct to me.

My original | JLCPCB corrected:

[image]

This is what my current board looks like:

[image]

My schematic:

[image]

To me that looks correct.

> 1N4148WS ([Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810101110_Jiangsu-Changjing-Electronics-Technology-Co---Ltd--1N4148WS_C2128.pdf), [JLCPCB](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Switching-Diode_Jiangsu-Changjing-Electronics-Technology-Co-Ltd-1N4148WS_C2128.html), [Footprint, Symbol & 3D Model](https://www.snapeda.com/parts/1N4148WS/Diotec%20Semiconductor/view-part/?ref=search&t=1N4148WS))

> PMBT3904 ([Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2105201004_Nexperia-PMBT3904-215_C8667.pdf), [JLCPCB](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Bipolar-Transistors-BJT_Nexperia-PMBT3904-215_C8667.html), [Footprint, Symbol & 3D Model](https://www.snapeda.com/parts/PMBT3904%2C215/Nexperia%20USA%20Inc./view-part/?ref=search&t=PMBT3904%20))

Comment: Do you want them to assemble the components, too?

Comment: yes they are assembling the components @tobalt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what causes the populated view to show up inverted, is that the pick and place file generated from KiCad ends up 180° rotated for polarized components *****. Therefore, they fix this to adjust the components to the orientation of their component feeder.

Let them resolve this. They usually know what you intend and how to realize it on their fab machines.

---

***** <sub>It doesn't mean that KiCad is wrong, or that they are wrong. It just means that they use different conventions, or rather that there doesn't seem to be a convention.</sub>

Comment: Alright will do. Hopefully they will correct it the right way.